# How can I call a https endpoint by NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest in case of untrusted certificate?

Tags: ios, objective-c, https, nsurlconnection

I have an IOS6 app, that connects to a REST API to fetch some data.

I use NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest in my data fetcher class, and I call its methods by GCD async pattern with blocks from my controller classes. So far so good.

My problem, that I change the API endpoint to https, its certificate is self-signed (I know its secure problems etc, but it is out of question for now).

By using sendSynchronousRequest I can't bypass this problem, because to bypass it, I need to set delegate for NSURLConnection, but in case of sendSynchronousRequest I cant' set delegate, delegate methods just called in case of async calls.

I don't like async request calling, I adore this GCD/sync call pattern very much, it works like a charm, it simple and clear.

So how can I make calls to a https api endpoint by GCD and , NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest that bypasses untrusted certificate problem?

Thanks to all!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You answered your question already yourself:

> By using `sendSynchronousRequest` I can't bypass this problem, because to bypass it, I need to set delegate for `NSURLConnection`, but in case of `sendSynchronousRequest` I cant' set delegate, delegate methods just called in case of async calls.

You should really get used to the *asynchronous style*. The approach with a synchronous call within a `dispatch_async` call is suboptimal to say the least.

The method `sendSynchronousRequest` is for beginners and toy apps. IMHO, Apple should really deprecate this method and remove it in the next iOSs.

The method `sendAsynchronousRequest:queue:completionHandler:` is for demonstration purposes, sample apps, prove of concept, and very simple requests not using authentication and https.

Finally, using the asynchronous style with implementing the delegates is for "serious" and release apps. Any serious app should use https when talking to a dedicated server, unless the server is public and does not support https.

Once your have switched to asynchronous style, there might be an answer to your actual question. However, there is no need to bypass a certificate - rather you will use the certificate as it is used in the release app.

Comment: My problem, that I have a central fetcher class, that makes requests to the API. There are some dozens of that. So it is so easy to make these calls async by GCD, not by AsyncRequest. Then what is GCD for in this case? Nothing?

Comment: It's still easy as that. You "just" (not really just) need a class that wraps around `NSURLConnection` and basically provides the instance method `start` which asynchronously starts a connection, and a completion property whose block will be invoked when the connection finishes. You can then wrap this into a method that is basically the same as `sendAsynchronousRequest:queue:completionHandler:`. However, your class can implement the delegates as desired.

Comment: Okkey, I understand. I know delegation and use heavily in other cases, but IMO GCD is so nice in my app code in these data fetching cases, that I am really sad that I have to change it just because of this https thing. Thanks for your suggestions!

Comment: Note: the `NSURLConnection` used in the convenient APIs will likely use the "default" handling for authentication. That is, it _might_ already work for the "usual" cases. The official docs contain the details: please see `connection:willSendRequestForAuthenticationChallenge:` and `performDefaultHandlingForAuthenticationChallenge:`.